# refresh property placeholder mechanism at Spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, properties-file, spring-profiles

I have a `Spring` context xml file and a specific bean into it that created by a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` mechanism.
My problem is: When the application is working related properties file changes and I don't want restart application. I want reload related bean without restart application.

What is best solution for my goal?

Answer (score 1):

you can have a look at `ReloadablePropertiesAnnotation` on github https://github.com/jamesemorgan/ReloadablePropertiesAnnotation

this should just work by annotating your property like

```
@ReloadableProperty("dynamicProperty.myProperty")
private String myProperty;
```

you'll have to add some spring configuration as well see the example on github or in this blog http://www.morgan-design.com/2012/08/reloadable-application-properties-with.html

Under the hood, this is using Guava's EventBus to update the properties of your beans after the bean has been created.

Comment: is there any way by Spring and without additional utility?